# Report Viewer error when using parameters

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

My project correctly generates Crystal reports, but I use parameters to filter my report output. Whenever I click the export button on the report viewer the export option doesn’t pop out. And whenever I click the next page option parameter option/selection field keep popping out, then it goes back to the first page instead of going the next page.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code here? I can only assume that the problem is in SetParameterValue. How do you use the SetParameterValue? Do you have a subreport that has another parameter?

```
cr.SetParameterValue("@theparameter", thevalue);
cr.SetParameterValue("@thesubreportparameter", thevalue, cr.Subreports[0].Name.ToString());
```